# Using AWS lambda or Google Functions to run the a large number of parallel instances of the same script with different arguments

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud-computing, amazon-lambda

I have a script for collecting data for different social media hashtags. The script currently makes a bunch of sequential HTTP requests, formats the data into a Pandas data frame, and saves it to a csv. For very popular hashtags, it takes hours to run.

I need to run this program for 1000+ individual hashtags. To save time, I'd like to run many instances concurrently, say, 50-100 instances at a time, each collecting different hashtags.

Assuming I change the CSV portion to utilize a cloud storage service instead, what else do I need to do in order to accomplish what I'm describing? If I have a list of all the hashtags I need, how to I set up AWS lambda or Google Functions in order to execute these concurrently, so that 50-100 instances are always running until all the data is collected?

Answer (score 1):

In AWS I would use [Step Functions with Dynamic Parallelism](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-step-functions-support-for-dynamic-parallelism/) to achieve that.

*First Lambda* function will *emit the list of hashtags* that you want to crawl.

Then a *Second Lambda* will be called many times in parallel by the Step Function State Machine to *process each of the hashtags*.

The configs (e.g. hashtags) are passed around as JSON objects.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If your script could take hours to run, I think Cloud functions (GCP) is not an option for you. a Cloud Function can only be run for up maximum 9 minutes, default value is 60 seconds. After this time the functions is shut down.

If you want to keep an instance for hours as you mentioned, a better option could be to use Compute Engine or App Engine Standard with [Basic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types) that allows up 24 hours for HTTP request.